# RabbitMQ not connecting to Consumer

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, microservices

We are working in microservices, and we have the function to send the data to a 3rd party.

- The Order service is to create an order, and send the OrderData to RabbitMQ. That is ok.
- Then we have the Task service, where it handles the data pushed to the 3rd party.

Both of them working well. But sometime or somehow. The message could not be sent to the 3rd party.

The Task service is still running. Our solution is to restart the Task service, or restart Rabbit MQ.

And it works. We got it in frequence.

The service we are using is NestJS.

1. How do we check the message push to queue in Rabbit
2. The connection between Consumer and Rabbit ?

Comment: Hi, Did you had a look at RabbitMQ UI ? You can usually access it through https://[your-host]:15672/ 
Also it's your producers & consumers that will connect to RabbitMQ, not the contrary